# Why isn't this animation working in my react app?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I'm trying to get this animation to work in my react project. It's supposed to be a square that floats across the screen and back. The square shows up but the animation itself doesn't work. I tried downloading firefox to see if it was a browser issue, but it still doesn't work.

here is the square component that's supposed to float:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Sqaure = styled.div`
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #4e6bff;
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  left: -60px;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: square 25s linear alternate infinite;

  @keyframes sqaure {
      to{
         transform: translate(100vw, 100vh);
      }
  }
`;
const AnimatedShapes = () => {
    return <Sqaure/>;
}

export default AnimatedShapes;
```

The square isn't visible because it's at -60px top and left, but if you change them both to 0 you will see it.

Comment: you misspelled square when defining the keyframes

Comment: @PedroFeltrin Holy crap.. thanks dude